# Insert a list of lists of strings as CSV

Tags: csv

Given a list of lists, as returned e.g. by `pcsv-parse-buffer`, what's a correct way of inserting it to the buffer in CSV format ?

I looked at `pcsv.el` and `csv-mode.el` but could not find a function to do that.

I think the main point is to correctly escape commas and double-quotes within each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following snippet to do that. It uses a function from `Org Mode` to quote each field.

```el
  (let ((parsed (let ((pcsv-separator ?\;))
                  (pcsv-parse-buffer))))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (insert (mapconcat (lambda (line)
                         (mapconcat #'org-quote-csv-field line ","))
                       parsed "\n"))
    ; delete previous content
    (delete-region (point) (point-max)))
```

Comment: Doesn't this miss the final newline? The outer `mapconcat` only inserts newlines between lines.

Comment: @npostavs  thanks I didn't know a final newline is required. I wonder if there is code that relies on the newline though. At least it worked for me without it.

Comment: I think most code should handle it either way, but for example, if you `cat` a file without a final newline at the shell, the shell prompt will be printed together with the file's last line. And maybe some line-counting code will be off-by-1.